# Send X position as Variable inside a message

Tags: javascript, string, variables, socket.io

currently my only option is to work with strings on the client side.

I want to update the X position of the Player every second. But Is it possible to send a Variable as a string?

```
var x = 50;
function sendPos() 
{
io.sockets.emit("message", 'x');
}
setInterval(sendPos, 1000);
```

---

***The client is just a dumb terminal, the positions will get updated on the server side***

Right now I receive **X** not the variable **X**.

Is there a way to work around this? Or do I have to change how the Client Side receives data?

---

The Client-Side does a .split

Currently this is the only way to do it on the ClientSide; because I use a type of game maker on the client side, and the plugin works with strings.

[Construct 2 Socket.IO Plugin http://imageshack.us/a/img211/1664/clientside.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img211/1664/clientside.png)

So Is there any way in which I could send the data of the X variable to the Client in a string? Else I am going to have to change the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it now.
I had to change the code a bit so that the Client Side Plugin was able to read the Variable.

New Code:

```
io.sockets.emit("message", 'Pos,' + x);
```